# Fancybox gallery from one image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I would like to make the gallery run as a slide show on its own, according to fancybox "autoPlay    If set to true, slideshow will start after opening the first gallery item

```
Boolean; Default value: false"
```

Question is where does it need to be changed to true , or is there a script that needs to be put in with this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

All the examples on jsfiddle have HTML, JS and CSS code in the example.
does the JS code go in with the above script like after the last ; before closing script tag?

Comment: Consider reading some tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

> You can pass these options as key/value object to fancybox() method

meaning you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
       autoPlay: true,
       autoCenter: true // just to give another example
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks Hans, now to figure out the best way to show a folder of images with only one thumbnail.